# How to access GeoJSON attributes to render a dynamic bar chart using chart.js inside Leaflet JS?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, leaflet, chart.js, gis

I'm trying to make a web map to visualize population data and some other stats using Leaflet and Chart js. I made the population data on the map, but I'd like to show a horizontal bar chart on the map that changes when I click on a GeoJSON feature from the map (e.g.: columns of Pop_2019 and Pop_2010), but I just can plot an empty chart. Can anyone tell me how can I access those attribute and make them interactive on clicking ?!

[image: Web map image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Population Density</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin=""/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/Control.FullScreen.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="lib/Control.FullScreen.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <!-- add Chart JS  -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .chart-container {
        height: 250px;
        width: 300px;
      }    
      #info-pane {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        z-index: 400;
        padding: 1em;
        background: white;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Map div -->
    <div id='map'></div>

    <!-- Chart div container -->
    <div id="info-pane" class="leaflet-bar chart-container">
      <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>

    <!-- Population data -->
    <script src="popjs.js"></script>

    <!-- Leaflet map elements -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Define chart and options
        var myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var PopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
            type:'horizontalBar',
            data: {
                labels:['Unemployement','Poverty'],
                datasets:[{
                    label: 'population',
                    data: [],
                    backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                      'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'],
                    borderWidth : 1,
                    borderColor : '#777',
                    hoverBorderWidth: 3,
                    hoverBorderColor: '#000'                
                    }]
            },
            options:{
                title:{
                    display : true,
                    text:'Indices per governorate',
                    fontSize: 25
                }
            }
        })
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you add the data to the chart? I see only `data: [],` and because of that it is clear that the chart is empty

Comment: Yes you are right, I left it empty because I need to access data in the GeoJSON file and pass it to "data: []" directly, but I'm still working on it.

Comment: Please share the code where you call `L.geoJSON()`

Comment: here is:
geojson = L.geoJson(popTN, {
style: style,
onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);